# There was no file attached to the 'Refund Me' case during the chat

Tags: liveagent

**Start a Chat**

Enable and use sneak peek and assistance flags.

- The Build a Branded Chat project is a prerequisite to this module. You can't complete the challenges without a basic Live Agent implementation.
- Enable sneak peek and assistance flags in your Live Agent configuration.
- Start a chat and raise and lower one assistance flag.
- End the chat using the button on the console or chat window.
- **Close the Chat tab in the console and click Save if prompted. This will return you to the cases list view in the console. You must close the Chat tab in order to successfully verify this challenge.**

I've done everything, but I'm confused for the highlighted part. Could you please let me know what exactly they're expecting me to do that ?

[image]

**Now I have raised and lower down the assistance Flag.**

[image]

**Now I lowered down the assistance flag.**

[image]

[image]

This is the final list of cases created, but I dont see challenge is working.
[image]

I dont see that option to attached the file.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach a file using as shown below

[image]

For more information you can use below link:
[Live agent File Transfer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_transfer_files.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

[image: File Upload]

Comment: I dont see that option is enabled for me. Please see the updated post above.

Comment: Check the link given in answer. One more thing file transfer should be enabled in Live Agent configuration

Comment: Agent File Transfer Enabled Checked is enabled in my case. Still I am facing the issue. Hope you will provide the details with screen shot for better understanding.

Comment: Please check the update answer. Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: Its working now. Thnx